# Spring Realtime Data Sending With Database

Tags: spring-boot, real-time, server-sent-events

I'm having small e-commerce application with Spring boot, but I want to realtime the rest endpoint where the products are listed, so I want the rest endpoint to be updated if any product is updated or created.

I'm confused how to listen database in realtime. I found Sse for realtime data sending but i couldn't found how to do this with database
Can you please suggest a best methodology

Comment: rest isn't realtime. Rest protocol is a call and then an answer. So what you need to do is some sort of either polling from the client, use websockets. Or look into spring reactive.

Comment: There are many different solutions that depend on the type of database and type of architecture you have. For example, some use database triggers to feed a queue, some use pubsub systems on top of their application to publish when a change happens. Some databases allow you to do this out of the box, some don't. This question is way **too broad** to cover all of these.

Comment: I don't want to depend on any database so if i create listener for data changed or created can i use that with Sse ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate for managing Data. then use hibernate envers and process the model after create/update db.

my suggestion is whenever an action create/update happens in hibernate.

Hibernate envers will trigger and use Akka actor to process the event.

Hibernate -> hibernate Envers -> Akka (business layer) -> rest endpoint

Thanks,
Vimalesh

Comment: Is there simpler way ?

Comment: Nope. this is basic architecture you can improve this according to your requirement.
Akka actor is useful for this kind of event management.